# Url not found after upload the site to the server

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem after uploading my website over test server.
The site is done under symfony, and putting it on my server, the url to access it is the following one:

```
http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/nameOfMySite/app.php
```

The problem is that I would like to access it with the following URL for example: `http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/nameOfMySite`

because for the moment all the links that I put, like the page of connection, are innaccessible.

In local I do `http://localhost/login` and not `http://localhost/app.php/login`
On my server I am forced to do

`http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/nameOfMySite/app.php/login`

to access the page.

Is there a configuration to remove `"app.php" or "app_dev.php"` please?

I am lost, because apart from the homepage, there is no longer any page of my website is accessible.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Have you followed the [deployment guide for Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html)? Also considering you have to manually add `app.php` to your URL to get it to work, Your webserver has not been [configured to work with Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue few days ago. I have solve this changing my .htaccess file. All I ve done was implementing rewrite rule. See below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this will solve your problem too. Good luck